# How to determine if directory was created in current transaction?

Tags: winapi, txf

I have some file/directory managment tool based on TxF system. Basically it's working like this:

1. I'm creating transaction using `CreateTransaction` function.
2. Somewhere later in the code I'm creating many directories using `CreateDirectoryTransacted` function.
3. Later I need to determine if I already created directory from point (2) in given path being still in this transaction (no `CommitTransaction` called so far).

Is there some substitute to `PathFileExists` but working with transaction system?

Comment: if you're using >= c++17, [`std::filesystem::exists`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists)?

Comment: No way to do it. You should associate created directory paths with transactions in your code.

Comment: @yano No, it seems does not work with TxF transaction system - it tells me that directory not exists, but one line later ```CreateDirectoryTransacted``` returns for the same path ```ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to resolve this problem using `CreateDirectoryTransacted` and error code `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.

Here is how:
`CreateDirectoryTransacted` returns different error codes, one of them is `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`. I can use this specific error to determine if directory already exists. If it does not, and I just created it there is nothing to worry about - I can safely remove it in the same transaction using `RemoveDirectoryTransacted`. I'm aware there will be some minor overhead if a lot of create->remove directory happen, but it's just not my case. It's just how I get around this problem.

If somebody have idea for a better solution - I'm open to change correct answear to some more general solution.